# Post on wall - link & picture

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3

I am using AS3 with Facebook API 1.8.1 and I got a problem when trying to add a picture and link to the posts I'm posting on the users wall from my app.

This is the code I am using now (The code that actually works..)

```
public static function postOnWall(params:Object):void {
    var obj:Object = { 
        name:"title", 
        caption:"caption", 
        description:"description", 
        message:"This is a test message",
        access_token: Facebook.getAuthResponse().accessToken
    }
    Facebook.api("me/feed", postOnWall_complete, obj, URLRequestMethod.POST);
}
```

What I'm trying to add besides from this is a picture and a link  with the same post, but after I add the picture & link parameter to the object, I get error #2032 (It doesn't tell me what it is in details, something is just wrong..)
Here is the code that is failing:

```
public static function postOnWall(params:Object):void {
    var obj:Object = { 
        name:"title", 
        caption:"caption", 
        link:"http://google.com", 
        picture:"http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/dakirby309/windows-8-metro/256/Web-Facebook-Metro-icon.png", 
        description:"description", 
        message:"This is a test message",
        access_token: Facebook.getAuthResponse().accessToken
    }
    Facebook.api("me/feed", postOnWall_complete, obj, URLRequestMethod.POST);
}
```

Is there an easy way to see where the error is, or am I just going to have to guess what the problem is?
Very thankful for help!

Comment: I made some progress!  
I turned off:  Stream post URL security - Links in stream posts must go to app's Canvas or Website URL, and I was able to post to the wall! Now I just have to figure out what that means and how to enable it again and still make it work..

Comment: Your link (`http://google.com`) isn't on the same domain as your canvas url, so it looks like FB isn't allowing it. E.g. If your canvas url is points to `http://myserver.com`, any link would need to start with that as well. BTW, if you don't know it, you can check out the developer docs at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/feed/#publish